# using std::regex_search for get all file and folder that be have match with pattern

Tags: c++, regex

I want implemented search windows's, I use this :

```
int main()
{
 Search(L"C:\\Users", L"*.txt"); // or Search(L"C:\\Users", L"*.txt");
}

search(path, CString searchString)
{
 std::wregex searchPattern = GetPattern(searchString);
 result = RecursiveSearch(path, searchPattern);
 return result ;
}

RecursiveSearch(path, std::wregex searchPattern)
{
CString newPath = path + CString("\\*");
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
HANDLE fileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
fileHandle = FindFirstFile(newPath, &findData);
do
{
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != fileHandle)
    {
        if (std::regex_search(findData.cFileName, searchPattern))
        {
            if (findData.cFileName != std::wstring(TEXT(".")) && findData.cFileName != std::wstring(TEXT("..")))
            {
                std::wcout << (const wchar_t*)findData.cFileName
            }
        }
        if (findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if (findData.cFileName != std::wstring(TEXT(".")) && findData.cFileName != std::wstring(TEXT("..")))
            {
        RecursiveSearch(GenerateNewPath(path, ToCString(findData.cFileName)), searchPattern);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
} while (FindNextFile(fileHandle, &findData));
return allObject;
 }
```

this code is ok, it's running successfully. but response is not good.

Some results for this example is :

text.txt

debug-2017-12-18-150616.txt

d.txt.lnk // this isn't not good result

.

.

what is the problem? can you help me detect and fix the bugs?

Comment: Try to add $(end of string) add the end of your regex

Comment: Try `*\.txt$` as a matching pattern. You need to escape `.` if you want it to match exactly a dot and not any character.

Comment: Is `L"*.txt"` accepted as a valid pattern?  What does the `*` quantifier actually quantify in this case?

Comment: @Cylexx and if my pattern is "t*.txt" this always not work(bad result), do you why?

Comment: @G.M. no, in method and function GetPattern I changed pattern to regex standard

Comment: @asdadsasdwe d*.txt isnt a correct filename, Windows dont allow it

Comment: Then the most interesting part of your program is the implementation of `GetPattern`. Curiously, this is precisely the part you've neglected to show.

Comment: @Cylexx Suppose I have a file with name "teodor.txt" and my pattern is "t*.txt", this pattern must detect this file, right? but now this code isn't correct response

Comment: @IgorTandetnik do you have Suggest? I will be grateful

Comment: I suggest that you show the implementation of `GetPattern`, assuming you would like further assistance. I thought my message was pretty clear on this. In general, you should show a [mcve].

Comment: **File name expressions** are not regular expressions. Well, not in the sense that the usual regular expression grammars tell you how they work. They have their own set of rules, and regular expression packages do not apply those rules. "*.txt" is valid as a file name expression, but it is not a valid regular expression.

Comment: @PeteBecker ok, tanx, what is best solution?

Answer (score 0):

for pattern add flags :

```
std::regex_constants::icase | std::regex_constants::ECMAScript | std::regex_constants::optimize;
```

and add flags to regex_search function :

```
std::regex_constants::match_continuous
```

add $ to end of pattern